# X axis missing from barplot?

Tags: r, bar-chart, x-axis

I have a dataset showing data on all tornadoes that have happened in the US between 1950-2020. I would like to make a barplot showing the total count of tornados by state (st).

First, I got the sum of tornadoes by state using:

```
statecount = dplyr::count(tornadodata, st, sort = TRUE)
```

So the data now looks like this (there's 53 total rows):
[raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVezp.png)

And then I attempted to plot this using:

```
barplot(statecount$n, yaxt = "n")
axis(side=2, las=1, at=seq(0, 10000, by=1000))
```

This was the result:

[image: barplot]

I can tell that the graph itself is correct, but I don't know how to get the states to show up on the x axis? I've tried reducing the font size using `cex.axis`, and also tried rotating the labels using `las=2` inside the `plot(n)` call, but these haven't worked. Just as a test, I tried plotting only the top 5 states using:

```
barplot(head(statecount, 5)$n)
```

And still the x axis didn't show up. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, any pointers would be much appreciated.

---

## Data in `dput` format

```
statecount <- structure(list(
  st = c("TX", "KS", "OK", "FL", "NE", "IA", "IL", "MS", "MO", "AL"), 
  n = c(9055L, 4338L, 4029L, 3464L, 2923L, 2654L, 2609L, 2401L, 2381L, 2293L)), 
  row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(statecount)` or, if it's too big, of `dput(head(statecount, 10))`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas sure, here it is: structure(list(st = c("TX", "KS", "OK", "FL", "NE", "IA", "IL", 
"MS", "MO", "AL"), n = c(9055L, 4338L, 4029L, 3464L, 2923L, 2654L, 
2609L, 2401L, 2381L, 2293L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 0):

Function `barplot` needs a named vector to have x axis names. This vector can be created from the data with `setNames`.

```r
statecount <- structure(list(
  st = c("TX", "KS", "OK", "FL", "NE", "IA", "IL", "MS", "MO", "AL"), 
  n = c(9055L, 4338L, 4029L, 3464L, 2923L, 2654L, 2609L, 2401L, 2381L, 2293L)), 
  row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

sc <- with(statecount, setNames(n, st))
barplot(sc)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Since you are using dplyr pipes, a `ggplot2` solution would be

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(ggplot2)
  library(dplyr)
})

statecount <- structure(list(
  st = c("TX", "KS", "OK", "FL", "NE", "IA", "IL", "MS", "MO", "AL"), 
  n = c(9055L, 4338L, 4029L, 3464L, 2923L, 2654L, 2609L, 2401L, 2381L, 2293L)), 
  row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

statecount %>%
  mutate(st = reorder(st, n, decreasing = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(st, n)) +
  geom_col(fill = "grey") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Always read the full help page of the functions you use. Here `?barplot` reveals that you may use `names.arg=`.

```
barplot(statecount$n, names.arg=statecount$st)
```

[image]